How to write text on a button but on each button different text?
I have a class type UserControl since the class is very big and long with more then 800 lines i will try to add only the important parts.
I created a public text property:
private string _buttonText = "Button";  // Default text
public string ButtonText
{
    get { return _buttonText; }
    set
    {
        _buttonText = value;
        Invalidate();  // Redraw the button when text changes
    }
}

Then in the OnPaint event calling a method name DrawButtonText:
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    DrawButton();
    DrawButtonText(e.Graphics);
    base.OnPaint(e);
}

And the DrawButtonText method
private void DrawButtonText(Graphics graphics)
{
    using (Font font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold))
    {
        SizeF textSize = graphics.MeasureString(_buttonText, font);
        PointF locationToDraw = new PointF((this.Width / 2) - (textSize.Width / 2), (this.Height / 2) - (textSize.Height / 2));

        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White))  // Ensure text color contrasts well with button
        {
            graphics.DrawString(_buttonText, font, brush, locationToDraw);
        }
    }
}

And then example of using it in form1 constructor:
public frmMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Image originalImage = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Csharp Projects\Screen Recorder\Resources\pngimg.com - buttons_PNG152.png");
    Image resizedImage = ResizeImage(originalImage, new Size(100, 100));

    GlowButton.GlowButton glowButton1 = new GlowButton.GlowButton
    {
        ButtonText = "REC",  // Set the specific text for this button
        Image = resizedImage,
        Size = new Size(100, 100),
        Location = new Point(10, (this.ClientSize.Height - 100) / 2),
        ApplyDarkEffect = true  // Assuming you have this property to toggle the dark effect
    };

    this.Controls.Add(glowButton1);

    SetButtonBehavior(glowButton1, ButtonBehavior.Default);
}

and the DrawButton method code:
/// <summary>Drawing hub</summary>
private void DrawButton()
{
    if (this.Image == null)
        return;

    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
    Rectangle imageBounds = GetImageBounds(bounds, this.Image);

    // draw into a buffer
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_bmpBuffer))
    {
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        DrawBackGround(g, bounds);
        if (this.ImageMirror)
            DrawMirror(g, imageBounds);

        if (this.CheckStyle != CheckedStyle.None && this.Checked == true)
            _eButtonState = ButtonState.Checked;
        else if (this.CheckStyle != CheckedStyle.None && this.Checked == false && _eButtonState == ButtonState.Focused)
            _eButtonState = ButtonState.Normal;
        switch (_eButtonState)
        {
            case ButtonState.Checked:
                {
                    if (this.CheckStyle == CheckedStyle.Border)
                    {
                        DrawBorder(g, bounds, this.CheckedBorderColor);
                        DrawColoredImage(g, this.Image, imageBounds, this.ImageFocusedColor);
                    }
                    else if (this.CheckStyle == CheckedStyle.ColorChange)
                    {
                        DrawColoredImage(g, this.Image, imageBounds, this.ImageCheckedColor);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DrawColoredImage(g, this.Image, imageBounds, this.ImageFocusedColor);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case ButtonState.Disabled:
                {
                    if (this.ImageDisabledColor == Color.Transparent)
                        DrawFadedImage(g, this.Image, imageBounds);
                    else
                        DrawColoredImage(g, this.Image, imageBounds, this.ImageDisabledColor);
                    break;
                }
            case ButtonState.Focused:
                {
                    DrawColoredImage(g, this.Image, imageBounds, this.ImageFocusedColor);
                    if (this.FocusedMask)
                    {
                        DrawMask(g, bounds);
                        DrawBorder(g, bounds, Color.DarkGray);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case ButtonState.Hover:
                {
                    DrawGlow(g, this.Image, imageBounds);
                    DrawColoredImage(g, this.Image, imageBounds, this.ImageHoverColor);
                    break;
                }
            case ButtonState.Normal:
                {
                    DrawImage(g, this.Image, imageBounds);
                    break;
                }
            case ButtonState.Pressed:
                {
                    DrawColoredImage(g, this.Image, imageBounds, this.ImagePressedColor);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
    // draw the buffer
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle))
        DrawImage(g, _bmpBuffer, bounds);
}

The result and problem is after running the application first time there is a text "REC" as should be on the big red button.  but the "REC" text is also added on the all other buttons on the bottom.
And another problem is when I click the button the text "REC" in the big red button is gone.
The big red button is glowButton1.
I want that the "REC" text will be only on the big red glowingButton1 and if not added and set text to any other buttons don't write the text on them too. And when clicking the button that the text will remain.


I assume all the buttons mentioned here use the same class that contains all the code you provided as a base class?

Also, please add the code that creates the other buttons.

Please add the code for DrawButton() as well.

@JuanR added also the DrawButton method code.

I think you should treat the paint operation as an atomic one, as opposed to having calls to draw the background and calls to draw the letters, so instead of calling DrawButton or DrawButtonText individually, simply Invalidate the control any time anything related to the presentation of the control changes. For instance, change this:
public Image BackgroundImage
{
    get { return _imgBackgroundImage; }
    set
    {
        _imgBackgroundImage = value;
        if (_imgBackgroundImage != null)
            DrawButton(); //Avoid calling the DrawButton method on its own
    }
}

To this:
public Image BackgroundImage
{
    get { return _imgBackgroundImage; }
    set
    {
        _imgBackgroundImage = value;
        if (_imgBackgroundImage != null)
            Invalidate(); //Use this instead
    }
}

Also, change the order of the calls so that the base class' OnPaint method is called first, then you draw on top of it:
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{            
    base.OnPaint(e);
    DrawButton();
    DrawButtonText(e.Graphics);
}

Your OnPaint event handler is the only that one that should be drawing the background and letters.
As to why the other buttons are being painted in this manner, please provide the code that wires up the buttons that you dropped from the toolbox. As written, this should not affect other buttons.
